# Coordinate free Koszul-Tate resolution

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras, projective-resolution

Tate's original construction of the Koszul-Tate resolution involved choosing cocycles representing the cohomology to be killed. Where is it written in a coordinate free treatment, perhaps via a slitting of the module of indecomposables?